# Magento 2 I have product id and attribute ids, How can i automatically select that attributes in particular product?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

i am making one custom form where i am loading particular atrribute collection, and save attribute id in custom table with product id.
now at the moment when data save in custom table, i want that attribute automatically selected in product edit page backend.

Comment: If you have tried code, please share here, and give the some description.

Comment: i tried but stuck in between. @PayalPatel

Comment: please explain bit more